# How to read blob content appended as formData.append

Tags: javascript, php, blob

I would like to be able to read and pass the innerHtml content of an entire div including all the sub-elements server-side using PHP.
I have successfully managed to upload it as as a blob with

```js
function scriptSubmit() {
  var fd = new FormData();
  var container = document.querySelector('.textbody').innerHTML; //get the div with text elements
  var blob = new Blob([container], {
    type: "text/html"
  });

  fd.append('blob', blob, );

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhr.open("POST", "scripts.php");
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
      console.log(xhr.status);
    }
  }

  xhr.send(fd);
}
```

```html
<div class="textbody">
  <div><span>sample text 1</span></div>
  <div><span>sample text 2</span></div>
  <div><span>sample text 3</span></div>
  <div>More sample text</div>

</div>
<button type="button" onclick="scriptSubmit()"> Submit <button>
```

(and getting server response == 200 on XMLHttpRequest) but i am having trouble reading the blob as plain text.
My reason for doing this is I would like to be able to use the text as html input that I can parse server-side with another script or if possible within the same script. In short I would like to be guided on the server-side operations
Thank you

Comment: Is the blob conversion mandatory ? I have no idea what it looks like from PHP, could you share a `var_dump($_POST)` or any debug call ?

Comment: <?php
var_dump($_POST); returned array(0) { }

Comment: You need to run that code, not pasting it in a comment on SO.

Comment: I am using an external PHP script and I can't find where to input my PHP script am not sure how to run it here either please excuse my inexperience

Answer (score 0):

Remove the last ',' int  `fd.append('blob', blob, );`.

Check your variable $_POST server side with var_dump.

For help u, u can create a div like `<div id="output"></div>` and print the server response by changing this if

```
if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
   console.log(xhr.status);
}
```

into this if

```
if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
   console.log(xhr.status);
   document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
}
```

**EDIT :**

Data not in the $_POST but in the $_FILES

Comment: I created the div and am getting the same array(0) { } response from the server

Comment: In ur scripts.php u have just `<?php var_dump($_POST); `

Comment: Try to replace `fd.append('blob', blob, );` to `fd.append('blob', "test");`

Comment: I'm now getting **array(1) { ["blob"]=> string(4) "test" }**

Comment: I am guessing this means that the blob was initially not getting posted or something?

Comment: can u `console.log` this variable `container`

Comment: var_dump the $_FILES server side too

Comment: the `console.log` returns `<div><span>sample text 1</span></div>  <div><span>sample text 2</span></div>  <div><span>sample text 3</span></div> 
 <div>More sample text</div>`

Comment: the `xhr.responseText` is `array(1) { ["blob"]=> string(4) "test" } array(1) { ["blob"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(4) "blob" ["type"]=> string(9) "text/html" ["tmp_name"]=> string(46) "C:\Users\....\AppData\Local\Temp\php605E.tmp" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(220) } }`

Comment: yes Indeed thats it!! Thanks a lot @RudyD